# What's wrong with the way I am redirecting between two pages?

Tags: php, session, redirect

Again, extremely noob PHP question.

I have a very simple login page

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
    header('Location: main.php');
    exit();
  }
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if (try_login($user,$pass))
    {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
      header('Location: main.php');
      exit();
    }
  }
?>
<html> <!-- and login form below...  >
```

And also a very simple main page:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
  }
?>
<html> <!-- etc, etc -->
```

I expect the following things to happen:

1. If I navigate to http://localhost/main.php before logging in, I should be redirected to http://localhost/.
2. If I navigate to http://localhost/ and log in successfully, I should be redirected to http://localhost/.

Unfortunately, #2 doesn't happen. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: I guess you have a typo in #2. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: It wasn't a typo. I thought it would work. Now I changed the redirection to `header('Location: /')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into a race condition here.  I've run into it several times...you set some stuff in the session, but the next page doesn't see it.  This is usually caused by the browser requesting the second page so quickly that the first hasn't had time to write the session -- so the second doesn't see the changes to the session variables.

Try calling `session_write_close()` before you send your redirect header.

Answer (score 3):

You should use fully qualified url:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/main.php ');
```

Comment: This is misleading: It's not necessary to include the FQDN (fully qualified domain name). Hard-coding the host name is a nuisance when having a web server configured by virtual hosts or deploying the webapp on a different host. However, the fully qualified URL *is* necessary for redirecting to external sites.

Comment: Here is what RFC says http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: Is there a PHP variable I can use to retrieve the host name?

Comment: There are many you could use: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

You must use absolute URIs like `Location: /` or `Location: /main.php`.

Comment: While it's highly recommended to make the name absolute (and a few browsers will choke on it if it isn't), "must" is overstating just a little.  A lot of browsers will handle relative redirects.  Including most of the common ones.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing out that detail. The important thing here is that `Location: .` will definitely not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
  {
    header('Location: main.php');
    exit();
  }
```

How is the person supposed to log in? You redirect if the $_SESSION doesn't have the username set *BEFORE* you do any code that would actually set that variable. That makes the login code effectively unreachable.

Comment: @Mark: `$_SESSION['username']` might be already set because the user navigated to `http://localhost/` before logging out. Instead of showing the login form again, I want to redirect the user to the main page.